# Install Hive on Windows

Tags: hadoop, hive, derby

I am trying to install hive 3.1.2 on windows 10, hadoop 3.2.2.
I can start hadoop server and start hive shell by run "hive".
First problem is it show a lot of WARN:

```
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2021-09-09T21:01:22,001 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Found configuration file file:/C:/my_programs/hive_3.1.2/conf/hive-site.xml
2021-09-09T21:01:22,303 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
2021-09-09T21:01:23,557 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
Hive Session ID = f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/C:/my_programs/hive_3.1.2/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2021-09-09T21:01:25,309 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/admin/f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358
2021-09-09T21:01:25,317 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Created local directory: C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Temp/admin/f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358
2021-09-09T21:01:25,325 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/admin/f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358/_tmp_space.db
2021-09-09T21:01:25,345 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Using the default value passed in for log id: f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358
2021-09-09T21:01:25,345 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Updating thread name to f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358 main
2021-09-09T21:01:25,383 WARN [f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
2021-09-09T21:01:53,237 INFO [f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358 main] CliDriver - Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
hive>
```

It still run hive shell when I start run

```
hive> show databases;
```

it come to error like this:

```
hive> show databases;
2021-09-09T21:05:01,341 INFO [f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Using the default value passed in for log id: f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
2021-09-09T21:05:43,092 INFO [f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Using the default value passed in for log id: f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358
2021-09-09T21:05:43,093 INFO [f879881f-c49b-449b-b8cf-81302c585358 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Resetting thread name to  main
hive>
```

I have read some solution and I think that problem come from hive metastore.
I followed by tutorial that connect derby metastore with hive.
But when I try to run

```
schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

Window cannot run schematool as a command line.
So I really confuse how can init db to hive, or can do in another way?

### Update 2021/9/20:

I have fix all variable in my paths, and right now I got stuck at new problem. The error is quite clear but no solution found on my research:

```
PS C:\my_programs\hive_3.1.2> .\bin\hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/my_programs/hive_3.1.2/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/my_programs/hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2021-09-20T20:22:34,274 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Found configuration file file:/C:/my_programs/hive_3.1.2/conf/hive-site.xml
2021-09-20T20:22:34,694 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
2021-09-20T20:22:37,728 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
Hive Session ID = 89fc5e06-2a55-496c-aea0-ab5512839ac3

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/C:/my_programs/hive_3.1.2/lib/hive-exec-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.impl.DfsClientConf.<init>(DfsClientConf.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
PS C:\my_programs\hive_3.1.2>
```

It seems like error at hdfs config. But I don't know what I need to do with hadoop config, core-site.xml or hdfs-site.xml, or st else. Do we need some config at hadoop side to connect with hive???

Comment: What's the error you are getting while running schematool? windows should recognize the command if you add environment variables for hive.

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I can run 'hive' as a command. So I don't know how Win cannot run schematool either @MohanaBC

Comment: You should be using `beeline` command. Hive command is deprecated. And you need to run schematool before you can have any databases

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I really confuse because I don't config any at hadoop side, to connect with hive, either at hive side. That process isn't auto, or is it?

Comment: There is a `hive-site.xml` that defines how Hive connects to its metastore and HDFS. In any case, `NoSuchMethodError` is generally a problem of a version conflict... I've not really used Hive3, so don't know what version you really need